# Search and One To Many Relation in SugarCRM

Tags: search, contacts, categories, sugarcrm

I'm trying to create tag-like category field for my contacts in SugarCRM. I've read through some docs, created a module and connected it with my contacts as 1 to N relation. The problem is, that Edit Form allows to choose only one category, but then you can add as many as you want in Contact View. 
But when you search, it only finds contact that have category set in edit form, but does not pay attention to other categories set in list.

What is the correct way to create 1 to N relation so all of the items would be used in search results?

thanks in advance, 
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a MultiSelect field for the tagging and it pick up correctly during searches.